# Magento - Owebia - Apply conditions for specific list of skus

Tags: magento-1.9, products, third-party-module, sku

Using Owebia, I need to apply a specific fee for certain product skus (from 001 to 099). I know the function I need to use with Owebia, but I don't know how to set the array of skus in the cart:

```
{
    "special_skus": {
    "label": "Restriction",
    "description": "Restriction",
    "shipto": "UK",
    "conditions": "array_match_any(SKUS_IN_CART), array('001','002'...[...]))",
    "fees": 200
}
```

Is there a way I can get this list? Should I do it in a different way? My final logic is more complicated: I just simply don't way to allow deliveries to some countries for certain products, but before I do that, I need to get something simpler working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I've finally found the correct configuration. You'll find my configuration file in here:

https://gist.github.com/PauGNU/1eb7045d660ebe61e51987554e3a1450

The steps to get this to work were:

1. First of all I created the basic rules for shipping (just weigth/destionation)
2. I created a rule which would only have a «condition» looking for products in the cart. This rule returns true when the products 003465 and 033339 are not present in the cart:

   ```
   "skus_es_gi_ad": {
   "conditions": "({count items where product.attribute.sku=='003465'} < 1) && ({count items where product.attribute.sku=='033339'} < 1)"
    }
   ```
3. Finally, in one of my width/destination rules I added this condition:

   ```
   "US_shipping": {
       "label": "United States",
       "description": "USA Shipping",
       "shipto": "US",
       "conditions": "{skus_es_gi_ad.conditions}",
       "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 0.5010:25.1460,1.0010:31.4820}"
    }
   ```